# Changing a user's nickname -- Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When a user's role gets updated, I would like the bot to append their username after Admin in their name Eg. `Admin | username` But it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name="Admin")
    if after in role.members:
          await after.edit(nick="Admin | " + discord.user, reason=None)
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work, is it not doing or anything or is it raising an error?

Comment: Well it changes the nickname to "Admin |" and raises the error "Must be str, not module" , so it just ignores discord.user

Answer (score 0):

`discord.user` is a class, we want a string that is the nick, user_name of the user.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name="Admin")
    if after.nick is not None and after.nick.startswith("Admin |"):
        return
    if after in role.members:
          await after.edit(nick="Admin | " + after.display_name, reason=None) #discord.user is a class, we want the member's new display name.
```

Comment: It works, but only with before.edit and before.display_name, and even then it gives the Nickname "Admin | Admin| DiscordName". Idk what the problem is.

Comment: I just realized it gives someone the "Admin" Prefix until the Nickname reaches its max. Length, so something just isn't doing its job

Comment: yeah it would go on a recursive loop, since after we update the nick name, on_member_update is called. will fix it

Comment: is it fixed yet?

Comment: Still gives the error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'"