# Discord.py - Role Prefix System

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So something's wrong with my Code, but i don't know what. I basically tried to code a Role Prefix System, that changes the Nickname of a User with a certain Role, in this case "Admin". It keeps giving me the error: "NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith" Could someone please help me? Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name="Admin")
   if after.nick.startswith("Admin | "):
       return
   if after in role.members:
       await after.edit(nick="Admin | " + after.display_name, reason=None)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing a user's nickname -- Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313852/changing-a-users-nickname-discord-py)

Comment: No it doesn't, that's why i commented under the answer but i didn't want to wait until you read it so i asked another question

Comment: I have already edited my answer to include your new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because the `nick` attribute is `None` / the member doesn't have a nickname, you should check if the nick attribute is None.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name="Admin")

    # Does this user has no nickname?
    if after.nick is not None:
        
        # OK, we can check if he / she has the Admin prefix
        if after.nick.startswith("Admin | "):
            # Looks like he already has one, let's just skip this
            return

    # Ok, he / she doesn't have a nickname (or doesn't have an admin prefix), we can continue our code

    if after in role.members:
        await after.edit(nick="Admin | " + after.display_name, reason=None)
```